# Embedding custom data into ELF file that will not get mmap'ed by ld.so

Tags: executable, elf

I have a 500MB file with some custom data (i.e. ZIP archive). I'd like to embed it to my ELF executable file, so that when I distribute the ELF file, I will be able to send only 1 file instead of 2 files.

The thing is that I don't want this 500MB ZIP data to get loaded by the OS automatically when my application starts. I want my application to open its own file, locate the data, and use this data in this "lazy" way.

On Windows, it would be possible to put this 500MB ZIP file to PE resources. This way this data wouldn't get loaded by executable loader.

Is there a place in the ELF format to embed such big amount of data in a way that it won't get mapped by the OS automatically?

I know I can append data to the end of the file, and then the OS should skip it during loading phase. But is it possible to use ELF structure to embed this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a place in the ELF format to embed such big amount of data in a way that it won't get mapped by the OS automatically?

This is trivial to do with ELF -- just put the data into a non-allocated section.

It's easiest to use `objcopy` to convert an arbitrary data file into a `.o` that can be linked in:

```
objcopy -I binary -B i386 -O elf64-x86-64 \
  --rename-section .data=.mydata,readonly,contents src dst.o
```

Comment: It seems that `dst.o` indeed has 500MB, but 99% of the file is all zeroes, instead of my file's content. When I remove `--rename-section`, `dst.o` does have my file inside it, but the 500MB is mapped by dynamic linker before my executable starts. Is this a bug in `objcopy` (v2.32) that when I use `--rename-section`, the resulting object file reserves the space, but does not include the content of my binary file? *Edit*: yes, I think it's a bug in `objcopy`, since `objcopy` on FreeBSD includes the file correctly with the same command line :(

Comment: OK, apparently this is NOT a bug, because after adding ",readonly,contents" to section flags, the issue goes away...

Comment: Is there any api to read/map the embedded data from within the program. I guess first step is to open /proc/self/exe. May be lookup the section table and locate offset/length of object ?