# Shared const data segment

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

We have to share a large chunk of compile-time known data between processes. Is it possible to put into .rodata section of a shared library? What are the practical steps to do so?

Comment: so why not just use any normal file?

Comment: @KamilCuk Total memory consumption between participating processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to put into .rodata section of a shared library?

Yes.

> What are the practical steps to do so?

If you declare the data `const`, compiler should *already* do it for you.
If that *isn't* already happening, please ask a separate question with an MCVE.

Or do you mean: "I have a data file which I'd like to include *verbatim* into my foo.so, without first transforming that data into a C-style array and compiling it?"

In that case, do this:

```
// foo.S
    .globl foo_data
    .section .rodata
foo_data:
    .incbin "foo.data"
```

compile `foo.S` and link it into your shared library.

Comment: I am thinking about c-style array but including binary data verbatim is a very interesting idea.

Comment: @zzz777 See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/57863507/50617

Comment: Sorry, I am not that familiar with using asm, can you give an example on how to access data from the assembly example in c++?

Comment: @zzz777 The example above gives the data `foo_data` label. In `C++` you would use `extern const char foo_data[];` and then use e.g. `foo_data[0]` to access the first byte of it.